# nginx protecting from screaming frog and too gready crawlers (so no real ddos, but close)

Tags: nginx

we have seen several actions where a simple screaming frog action would almost take down our server (it does not go down, but it slows down almost to a halt and PHP processes go crazy). We run Magento ;)

Now we applied this Nginx ruleset: https://gist.github.com/denji/8359866

But I was wondering of there is a more strict or better way to kick out too gready crawlers and screaming frog crawl episodes. Say 'after 2 minutes' of intense requesting we should already know someone is running too many requests of some automated system (not blocking the Google bot ofcourse)

Help and ideas appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how a simple SEO utility scan may cause your server to crawl, you should realize that blocking of spiders isn't real solution. Suppose that you have managed to block every spider in the world or created a sophisticated ruleset to define that this number of requests per second is legit, and this one is not.

But it's obvious that your server can't handle even a few visitors at the same time. Few more visitors and they will bring your server down, whenever your store receives more traffic.

You should address the main performance bottleneck, which is PHP.

PHP is slow. With Magento it's slower. That's it.

Imagine every request to your Magento store causes scanning and parsing of dozens and dozens of PHP files. This will hit the CPU *so* bad.

If you have unoptimized PHP-FPM configuration, this will hit your RAM so bad also.

These are the things which should be done in order of priority to ease the PHP strain:

## Make use of Full Page Cache

Really, it's a must with Magento. You don't loose anything, but only gain performance. Common choices are:

- [Lesti FPC](https://github.com/GordonLesti/Lesti_Fpc). This is easiest to install and configure. Works most of the time even if your theme is badly coded. Profit - your server will no longer be down and will be able to serve more visitors. It can even store its cache to Redis if you have enough RAM and you are willing to configure it. It will cache, and it will cache things fast.
- Varnish. It is the fastest caching server, but it's tricky to configure if you're running Magento 1.9. You will need Turpentine Magento plugin. The latter is quite picky to make work if your theme is not well coded. If you're running Magento 2, it's just compatible with Varnish out of the box and quite easy to configure.

## Adjust PHP-FPM pool settings

Make sure that your PHP-FPM pool is configured properly. A value for pm.max_children that is too small will make for slow page requests. A value that is too high might hang your server because it will lack RAM. Set it to (50% of total RAM divided by 128MB) for starters.

Make sure to adjust pm.max_requests and set it to a sane number, i.e. 500. Many times, having it set to 0 (the default) will lead to "fat" PHP processes which will eventually eat all of the RAM on server.

## PHP 7

If you're running Magento 2, you really should be using PHP 7 since it's twice as fast as PHP 5.5 or PHP 5.6.

Same suggestions with configs in my blog post [Magento 1.9 performance checklist](https://www.getpagespeed.com/web-apps/magento/magento-1-9-performance-checklist).